# Why do I not get 20151231 when input is 2.0151231E7F

Tags: c#, floating-point

Simple question:

```
Console.WriteLine("Double: " + 2.0151231E7);
```

Double: 20151231

```
Console.WriteLine("Single: " + 2.0151231E7F);
```

Single: 2.015123E+07

**Why?**

---

Background: I'm consuming a soap web-service where an element is declared:

```
<xsd:element name="VALUE_FROM" type="xsd:float" />
```

In the soap response it looks like this:

```
<VALUE_FROM>2.0151231E7</VALUE_FROM>
```

But I'm getting 20151230 instead of 20151231.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

20151231 has 25 digits in binary. A `float` only has [24 binary digits in the mantissa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format).

So the last bit had to go.

Comment: The URL you cite does not support the statement that a float has only 24 bits in the mantissa. It does not use the term “mantissa” at all, because this is the wrong term. A mantissa is the fractional part of a logarithm. The fractional part of a floating-point representation is the significand.

Comment: Both terms are used, @EricPostpischil. Just not in that specific article.

Comment: The word “mantissa” does not appear in the 1985 or 2008 IEEE 754 standards. Its use in reference to floating-point is sloppy and misleading.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right, it does not appear there. It *does* however appear nearly everywhere else. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point has it as alternative name, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I've chosen this as the answer because it picks up my example number and therefore was the most understandable for me.

Comment: From the page you cite: “Use of mantissa in place of significand or coefficient is discouraged, as the mantissa is traditionally defined as the fractional part of a logarithm, while the characteristic is the integer part.”

Comment: This explanation about the mantissa is an errornous assumption from Knuth. "Mantissa" has been used centuries before from the Middle Ages, the word "significand" is not older than 1946. So Knuth/Wikipedia is wrong.

Comment: @ThorstenS.: What does the age of a word have to do with its suitability for a particular purpose? The IEEE 754-2008 standard defines “significand” as a component of a finite floating-point number containing its significant digits (2.1.49). To discuss a technical issue precisely, use specified, standardized language. If you want to avoid words placed in use after 1946, you are going to have a tough time in the computer field.

Comment: The question is not what is defined in a standard, I answered to your assertion "It does not use the term “mantissa” at all, because this is the wrong term.". It is *not* the wrong term because "mantissa" has been used by older mathematicians with exact the same meaning as your favored term "significand". A word can have several meanings, I do not see a reason to forbid the word "power" in language or physics because it has a very specified meaning in mathematics.

Comment: "mantissa" is frequently used in this sense.  I would not go so far as to call it wrong, but it is slightly unfortunate because it causes some confusion between floating-piont and logarithmic representations (which are increasingly commonly used in FPGA settings).  Certainly in technical writing, "significand" ought to be used, as that is the language of the technical standards.  In more casual settings, I have a hard time getting too excited about the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the precision of Float (IEEE 754) versus the Double data type - the latter having more precision, thus the number can be fully represented.

The [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) standard which defines how single precision floating point numbers are represented in a computer specifies only 24 bits of precision (information) for the significand (fraction) and 8 bits of information for the exponent.

Comment: +1 for correctly using “significand” instead of “mantissa” (which is properly the fractional part of a logarithm, not the fractional part of a floating-point representation).

Comment: Thanks and also +1 for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's just because a float (represented in .Net by [System.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) is simply not precise enough.

You can have a way better precision by using double instead of float, but you will still have some (but far less) approximation.

If you want to manipulate integers without any loss of precision, use integer types (int, uint, long, ulong, etc...)

From the documentation:

> **Floating-Point Values and Loss of Precision**
>
> Remember that a floating-point number can only approximate a decimal
>   number, and that the precision of a floating-point number determines
>   how accurately that number approximates a decimal number. By default,
>   a Single value contains only 7 decimal digits of precision, although a
>   maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally. The precision of a
>   floating-point number has several consequences:
>
> Two floating-point numbers that appear equal for a particular
>   precision might not compare equal because their least significant
>   digits are different.
>
> A mathematical or comparison operation that uses a floating-point
>   number might not yield the same result if a decimal number is used
>   because the floating-point number might not exactly approximate the
>   decimal number.
>
> A value might not roundtrip if a floating-point number is involved. A
>   value is said to roundtrip if an operation converts an original
>   floating-point number to another form, an inverse operation transforms
>   the converted form back to a floating-point number, and the final
>   floating-point number is equal to the original floating-point number.
>   The roundtrip might fail because one or more least significant digits
>   are lost or changed in a conversion.

Comment: Thanks but in this case the data type is determined by the web-service that I have to consume.